# Does spring data uses the new MongoDB Bulk API for bulk operations?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, nosql

see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/

Can you please point me to the version which supports this new API or in which version this support will be available?

Comment: See the database `command` forms, particularly for [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/update/) and [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/insert/). The basic `command` method has always been available in every driver and is in fact the basis of how everything communicates with the database server. The actual availability of this is dependent on the **server** version though and not the client API.

Comment: @Niel Lunn Is the new bulk API or new 2.6 write commands supported out of box by spring data mongodb? If not when they will be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no dedicated support for the bulk operations introduced in MongoDB 2.6. If you think these operations are worthwhile to add support for, please raise a ticket in out [JIRA](http://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO).

In the meantime you can use a `CollectionCallback` to execute bulk operations on the raw MongoDB collection:

```
template.execute(new CollectionCallback<Void> {

    Void doInCollection(DBCollection collection) {

        BulkWriteOperation operation = collection.initialize(Uno|O)rderedBulkOperation();
        // bulk code goes here
        operation.execute();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, I have created a JIRA for this https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-934

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Java Driver for MongoDB v2.6 does support bulk operations however since these are very new set of operations which were not provided in MongoDB v2.4, these may not have made into  stable versions of Spring Data yet. I see there are planned 1.5.X SpringData but don't see any associated API / reference for these yet on their website.